# How to use global variable inside do_shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this variable working well

```
<?php $dlm_download->the_title(); ?>
```

but when i put it inside an existing do_shortcode it return a empty value

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[sdfile url='http://example.com/goto-php-2?file=".$dlm_download->the_title()."']"); ?>
```

I am using the [Download Monitor plugin for WordPress](https://github.com/download-monitor/download-monitor).

**note the solution provided by rnevius is only work with the legacy version of the plugin,but it doessn't work with the current version of Download monitor plugin

Comment: Most probably the method of `the_title()` echoes something on its behalf, and you're expecting that thing as a returned value, don't you?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the_title()` is the wrong method to use here, as it `echo`es the title. Rather, you should be using `get_the_title()` (which `return`s the title):

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[sdfile url='http://example.com/goto-php-2?file=".$dlm_download->get_the_title()."']"); ?>
```

More information about this method can be found [in the source](https://github.com/download-monitor/download-monitor/blob/master/includes/class-dlm-download.php#L117).

Comment: after one day of usage, i see it works only with legacy version of Download  Monitor Plugin but it does't work with current version of this plugin and when I implement a mentioned code as you provide me it returns a blank value .. so any help